# check if pandas df is empty with apply - python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to execute a function only when a df is not empty. Otherwise, the function should do nothing. `if not df.empty:` would work fine normally but I want to incorporate the same logic within a row wise function.

I need a row-wise function to send out rows as individual instances. However, I only want to send these instances when there are non-null values.

Using below, the row wise function will record 3 values, thereby executing the print statements. I'm aiming to perform a similar output to scenario 1.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': ['2020/01/30 14:00:00', '2020/01/30 14:00:00'],
           'Item': ['Apple','Apple'],
           'Cost': ['1','1'],
            })

df = df.drop_duplicates(keep = False)
```

Scenario 1:

```
if not df.empty:
    print(df['Datetime'])
    print(df['Item'])
    print(df['Cost'])
else:
    pass
```

Scenario 2:

```
def func(df):

    print(len(df))

    if not df.empty:
        print(df['Datetime'])
        print(df['Item'])
        print(df['Cost'])
    else:
        pass 

df.apply(func, axis = 1)
```

Comment: What is the goal of the operation you are trying to perform? Why are you applying func to each row with apply and axis=1? Are you trying to output the value of a specific column only when the row is not empty?

Comment: Outputting the value of columns only when the row is not empty

Comment: I think you need to explain with an example. Your explanation does not clearly state why `df.apply(func, axis=1)` should be used instead of `func(df)`. What is the context for this attempt?

Comment: In addition, it is important to note that most attempts to handle empty dataframes are not the best way to deal with Pandas. Typically, you encounter empty dataframes when you try to handle dataframes with a loop structure and need to process them. However, in most cases, there are other more efficient ways than using a loop.

Comment: I'm sending rows as individual df's. I need to iterate over row by row using `apply()` or `df.iterrows`. Would checking for notnull() work?

Comment: Try to express the actual task you want to perform with an [mre]. It is likely that you will not need a loop like `apply` or `iterrows`.

Comment: I'm having a hard trying understanding your your insistence. Are you saying that `apply` or `iterrows` shouldn't be used or that they shouldn't be used to output the value of columns when not empty?

Comment: Most Pandas problems can be solved quickly, and questions that don't get an answer within 30 minutes are generally questions that need improvement. However, it takes too much of my time and effort to improve the questions (although I think I have explained enough). Let's just believe that someone will answer.

Comment: I've now included a full description. It's more confusing to me but hopefully the detail will help. I obviously can't add in user email credentials but it's clear why I need to iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you want to send one email per row, you will invariably need to iterate over them.

From your example dataframe, there aren't any "empty rows", so there's no need to skip anything row-wise. You can use `iterrows` and just call your function to send the email with the data from each row, accessing each column with the syntax `row[col_name]`. If `df` is empty, there simply won't be any loops and nothing will be executed.

In the example below you can see how you can access the data in each row:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print(f"sending email {i}:")
    print(f'{row['Datetime'] = }')
    print(f'{row['Item'] = }')
    print(f'{row['Cost'] = }')
```

This will print:

```
sending email 0:
row['Datetime'] = '2020/01/30 14:00:00'
row['Item'] = 'Apple'
row['Cost'] = '1'
sending email 1:
row['Datetime'] = '2020/01/30 14:00:00'
row['Item'] = 'Apple'
row['Cost'] = '1'
```